# How to use Change Detection in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to fire of required fields validation when a change occurs on my component. There are multiple required fields on this component which needs to be filled out in order for user to proceed to next page. My thought was to fire off my function which checks for required fields if any of them are null or empty.

My problem is that I am not able to find any example on how to implement this. Below is what I have gotten so far.

```
    import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CarReqFormService } from './carReqForm.service';
import { DropDownListItem } from './carReq-dropdownItem';
import { IMyOptions, IMyDateModel } from 'ngx-mydatepicker';
import { surgeryReservationModel } from './carReservationModel';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { AutoCompleteBoxRequest } from './autoCompleteBoxRequest';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'uh-carReservationFormPage3',
    templateUrl: './carReservationFormPage3.html',
    providers: [carReqFormService]
})



export class carReservationFormPage3Component implements OnInit {

    SurgicalPositionItems: DropDownListItem[];
    private loading: boolean = true;
    carReservationModel = new carReservationModel();
    public isBusy: boolean;


    constructor(private _carRequestFormService: carReqFormService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute ,
                private _router: Router,
                private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    } 
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getActivecaricalPositions();
        this.isBusy = true;
        var test;
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this._carRequestFormService.getcarRequestById(+params['id']))
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.carReservationModel = data;
                this.isBusy = false;


            },
            error => {
                console.log("Error", error);
                this.isBusy = false;
            },
            () => {
                console.log("Inside NgOnInit on Page 3" + this.carReservationModel.carRequestId);
                this.isBusy = false;
            });


    }




}
```

Is there a function which gets fired on any change which I can call for firing my function to go over validation rule ?

Comment: ngDoCheck is fired whenever Angular performs change detection for your component, onChanges is fired when @Input change, but there's nothing else

Answer (score 0):

i would say why don't use reactive form instead of change detection. its is very easy implement.

you can easily implement your validation part using `Validators` and you can hide next button if validation is failed.

more info check this link
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Note:- why are defining service in your component. Is it shared service or component level.

```
 providers: [carReqFormService]
```

if its shared component than you need define in the module level. other wise it will create sperate instance